# Space utilization in DBMS_REDEFINITION package in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, dbms-redefinition

I am trying to create partitions on pre-existing tables in my application. While doing same, I am facing space issues in the schema's default tablespaces.

Could someone please explain how the DBMS_REDEFINITION package works in terms of space utilization. Do it requires extra space to perform the task. If yes , why? And is it temporary ? do it release the space after completing the redefinition

Immediate Comments on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you use DBMS_REDEFINITION package to redefine a table you need twice the space which is used by your table. Actually DBMS_REDEFINITION copies all data from old table to new table. You have to drop the old table manually after successfull redefition.

Comment: thank you for telling that. There is one more things for which i am facing issues related to same. We have found a performance dergrade in the application after partioning the tables. Could you please help for my  query in the link => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25929178/performance-degradation-after-partioning-tables-using-dbms-redefinition-package